# _fullPath and widechar strings

Tags: string, winapi, path

I'm trying to execute the following code but I'm getting an error saying "expression:string subscript out of range".

```
wstring relPath = L"..\new\test.txt";
wstring absPath;

_wfullpath(&absPath[0],&relPath[0],_MAX_PATH);
```

`_wfullpath(wchar_t *absPath,const wchar_t *relPath, size_t maxLength)` expects a pointer to a wide char string for absPath and relPath and that's exactly what I'm passing in (correct me if I'm wrong).
I'm not sure that simply declaring the absPath as wstring, memory is being allocated for it and that might be the problem.

could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
std::wstring relPath = L"..\\new\\test.txt"; // Escape backslashes.
std::wstring absPath;

wchar_t* absPathBuf = _wfullpath(0, relPath.c_str(), _MAX_PATH );
if (0 != absPathBuf)
{
    absPath = absPathBuf;
    // delete[] absPathBuf; <-- This was wrong, malloc() is used by _wfullpath()
    free(absPathBuf);
}
```